# Right and left stabilizers

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $A$ is a finite subset of a group $G$. Let $L$ ($R$) denote the set of all those group elements that fix $A$ from the left (right): $$L:=\{g\in G\colon Ag=A\},\quad R:=\{g\in G\colon gA=A\}.$$ It is easily seen that $L$ and $R$ are subgroups of $G$, and also that $L=R$ in the commutative case. Is it true that $|L|=|R|$ in the general case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not true in general.

Note that if $g\in L(A)$, then we can partition $A$ into sets of the form $\{a,ga,g^2a,\ldots\}$. If we have just one such set, then $L(A)=\langle g\rangle$, and $R(A)=\langle a^{-1}ga\rangle$. To find a counterexample, we therefore need at least two such subsets.

Here's a simple situation, where we take $G=S_4$, $g=(12)$, and $A=\{g^r(123)\}\cup\{g^r(34)\}$, so
$$ A = \{(123),(23),(34),(12)(34)\}. $$
Now $g\in L(A)$ by construction, but we can quickly check that $R(A)$ is trivial.